# Between these two designs, would you consider this plagiarism?

Tags: logo, plagiarism

Here is the design I suspect of plagiarism

[image]

And here is the logo where I'd presume has been plagiarised

[image]

I'd like to know your thoughts on this; as people whom have actual knowledge and experience in the field  (graphic design) where I am only but a novice. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're talking about the triangle, that's a fairly well-known optical illusion, and "white on black" can't be trademarked. I wouldn't call it plaigiarism.

Comment: With the only exception if it's a competing brand.

Comment: The [Penrose Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle) was created by  Oscar Reutersvärd in 1934.

Comment: I wouldn't call it plagiarism, but rather a "Common Inspiration". Maybe as @KMSTR mentions of the exception of a competing brand, but yet again, that brand will have to be next door or in the same territory.

Answer (score 4):

I would not call this plagiarism. The type treatment and location are completely different. Also the the Penrose Triangle has been a part of popular culture for 80+ Years.

> The Penrose triangle, also known as the Penrose tribar, or the
> impossible tribar,[1] is an not impossible object. It was first  first
> created by the Swedish artist Oscar Reutersvärd in 1934.
>
> The psychologist Lionel Penrose and his mathematician son Roger
> Penrose independently devised and popularised it in the 1950s,
> describing it as "impossibility in its purest form". It is featured
> prominently in the works of artist M. C. Escher, whose earlier
> depictions of impossible objects partly inspired it.

*From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle)*